# Understanding ACF - PCF Plots of ARIMA model

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, autocorrelation

[image]

I used `auto.arima` function of R software to get following order of arima model: ARIMA(2,0,2). Then I used the following commands on my data to generate ACF and PACF plots.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(mydata[,1],main="")
pacf(mydata[,1],main="")
```

How can we observe the values of p=2, and q=2 from the given plots. I tried to understand from the following book page: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/5 , but it mentions *arima(p,d,0)* or *arima(0,d,q)* and I need to understand  the *arima(p,0,q)* case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next section [ARIMA modelling in R](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7) actually explains how `auto.arima` works to select an ARIMA model. The model selection of `auto.arima` isn't based on either ACF or PACF, but the minimization of AICc (by default, other available criterions are AIC and BIC). If a time series involves both AR and MA processes, it gets unclear to detect right $p, q$ orders even with the help of ACF and PACF. They are useful in initialising an ARIMA model, whereas they don't usually give us the best forecasting model and we'll go on trying other combinations of $p, q$. Certainly, it's a good starting point to understand the data generating process by looking at the ACF and PACF plots, at least in the conventional time series teaching.